# how can I make function being executed?

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, self-executing-function

I wrote below script. it works fine with my html editor. But, viwing on the actual website, the function does not run, displaying the innerHTML blank. How can I fix it? Is this problem something I need to see about self-executing function?

```
 for (i=0;i<2;i++)
 {                              
     document.getElementById(tdHD3hour[i]).innerHTML = myhd.HDD(x[i].getAttribute("T"));
  }  

var myhd = {
    HDD: function (a) { 
    if (a>=15.5){
        hdd = 0;
    } else {     
         hdd = (15.5-a)/8;
    } return hdd;
           }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you did not define `myhd` first. Flip those around:

```
var myhd = {
    HDD: function hd(a) { 
    if (a>=15.5){
        hdd = 0;
    } else {     
         hdd = (15.5-a)/8;
    } return hdd;
           }
 }

 for (i=0;i<2;i++)
 {                              
     document.getElementById(tdHD3hour[i]).innerHTML = myhd.HDD(x[i].getAttribute("T"));
  }
```

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/dx965j72/)